# Flash: How to safely capture and ignore security violations

Tags: flash, security, sandbox, cross-domain-policy

Our app is making frequent URL requests to another domain which are not dependent on the app to function normally. Occasionally, for some reason it fails to download the crossdomain.xml from the remote domain, which results in the app throwing a sandbox security violation.

As these URL requests are not required for the app to function normally, I would much rather capture and ignore the security sandbox violations and keep the app running. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [`SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html#event%3asecurityError), which is dispatched by `URLLoader`.

To answer your comment:

Yes, the cross domain file isn't actually looked for until you request data:

> Note that even though the method name is `loadPolicyFile()`, the file isn't actually loaded until a network request that requires a policy file is made.
>   Source: [`loadPolicyFile()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Security.html#loadPolicyFile%28%29)

Meaning you can use the above event to manage failed loads.

Comment: This looks to be exactly what I want. Am I correct in assuming that the crossdomain.xml is downloaded when URLLoader.load is called, before it actually makes the URL request? If I catch the SecurityErrorEvent, I could potentially retry URLLoader.load to see if it successfully downloads the crossdomain.xml and succeeds with the URL request?